# google sitemap generator installation selinux

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, selinux

when i trying to install google sitemap generator i received this error

```
Change security context of to system_u:object_r:httpd_modules_t install: WARNING:
ignoring --context (-Z); this kernel is not SELinux-enabled Program files 
successfully copied. ./install.sh: line 488: 14284 Segmentation fault 
"$DEST_DIR/$BIN_DIR/$DAEMON_BIN" update_setting $update_setting_flags 
"apache_conf=$APACHE_CONF" "apache_group=$APACHE_GROUP" > /dev/null
```

after choosing the submiting file settings

i tried to unistall it & excute this

`getenforce` try again but the same problem

when i enter this dir `/etc/sysconfig/selinux.` it is not contain the selinux file

my os `centos 6  X86_64`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after 2 days of troubleshooting & testing & searching more & more the solution is [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-sitemap-generator/SuqrgGL1QiM)

Comment: What was the solution? Just providing a link to a forum is useless.

Comment: the solution is changing the files permissions & owner/group